# Present perfect in subordinate clause

Tags: tense

The following sentence is given (M. Swan - Practical English Usage):

> It's been a good time while it's lasted.

I can't get the point of the sentence. Why can we use the present perfect in the subordiante clause at all? I thought the past progiressive more suitable.

> It's been a good time while it was lasting.

Comment: Even clear is - *It's been a good time till the end!*

Comment: @MaulikV The thing is the verb _last_ have a similiar meaning as _go on_ in the point of translating to my native language. I can't bound it with an idea of completion (i.e. the perfect aspect). Could you clarify?

Comment: In American English you'll find this idea expressed exactly as user3169 has given it. The example from Swan is something you might hear at Downton Abbey. If there is a nuanced difference between them, it is that the Downton fellow is feeling rueful about the passing of the good time *even as it begins to fade away*. It isn't gone yet, but in the very near future it will be a thing of the past.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea how they came up with that example.

I would say:

> It **was** a good time while it **lasted**.

using simple past tense. The time span in the past is implied without making it more complicated.